# No module named pandas - python path or sys path import issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm new to Python and am struggling to understand imports and path locations, especially with `sys path` and `PYTHONPATH`.

**Python 3.6.2**

I'm trying to hit an API route in `http/routes.py`, then Import `drivers/test_driver.py` so I can run functions inside of it.

> ImportError: No module named pandas

Bootstrapping app with Flask, running at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=http/routes
$ flask run
```

**routes.py**

```
import sys
import os
from flask import Flask, url_for

from drivers.test_driver import * ####### BREAKING

app = Flask(__name__)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))

@app.route('/')
def api_root():
    return 'Welcome'

@app.route('/drivers')
def api_drivers():
    # Do something with imported drivers functions
    return 'All Drivers Ready'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**test_driver.py**

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
print('Path: ', sys.path[len(sys.path)-1]) # '/Users/myname/Desktop/project/Lambda/drivers_app/drivers/..'
import pandas as pd
import boto as bt

def run():
    df = pd.read_csv('s3 location', engine='python')
    return 'this is working'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    output = run()
    print(output)
```

File structure:

[image]

Comment: Since you say you're new to Python, it's probably best to cover the basic bases - have you installed pandas? If you get rid of `import pandas` do you get the same issue with `import boto`?

Comment: @roganjosh yes pandas is installed and yes I get the same error when installing `boto`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're either not using a virtual environment, it's configured incorrectly, or perhaps you just forgot to activate it in the shell where you're running `flask run` from. (You should always use a virtual environment when developing Python projects; one virtualenv per project). I'm not familiar with the specifics on ... whatever OS you're running, so I recommend reading and following the first few sections of the [Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/).

If you're unsure if your shell has a virtualenv activated, you can always do `which python` (or whatever the windows equivalent is, if that's your thing) and it should print a path to where your virtualenvs are located, and not the system python.

Until you're getting into some advanced use cases, messing with `sys.path` is a huge red flag. You shouldn't have to do that. I would move the `drivers` module (module == a folder w/ an `__init__.py` file) into the `http` module (folder), so you have

`$ tree
.
└── http
    ├── drivers
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test_driver.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── routes.py`

and inside `routes.py`, you'd use a relative import and do `from .drivers.test_driver import run` (using `from whatever import *` is generally considered bad practice). That should alleviate the need to mess with `sys.path`.